# Probability of getting a perfect score on multi-part test

Tags: probability

> An exam has parts $A$ and $B,$ both of which must be completed. In part $A$ you
> can choose between answering $10$ true-false questions or answering $8$ multiple
> choice questions, each of which has $5$ choices. In part $B$ you can choose between
> answering $12$ true-false questions or $6$ multiple choice questions, $3$ choices each.
> If one guesses on each question, what is the probability of getting a perfect
> score?

Let $E$ denote the event of getting a perfect score, $E_1$ the event choosing true-false questions on part $A$ and true-false questions on part $B.$ $E_2$ the event of choosing true-false questions on part $A$ and multiple choice questions on part $B.$ $E_3$ the event of choosing multiple choice questions on part $A$ and true-false questions on part $B.$ And, lastly, $E_4$ the event of choosing multiple choice questions on part $A$ and multiple choice questions on part $B.$ Conditioning,

$$P(E)=\sum_{k=1}^4P(E\,\vert\,E_k)P(E_k)=\frac14\left[P(E\,\vert\,E_1)+P(E\,\vert\,E_2)+P(E\,\vert\,E_3)+P(E\,\vert\,E_4)\right]$$
*assuming* that the test taker chooses each section equiprobably and independently. It follows

$$P(E)=\frac14\left[\left(\frac12\right)^{10}\left(\frac12\right)^{12}+\left(\frac12\right)^{10}\left(\frac13\right)^{6}+\left(\frac15\right)^{8}\left(\frac12\right)^{12}+\left(\frac15\right)^{8}\left(\frac13\right)^{6}\right]\approx3.95\cdot10^{-7}.$$
However, the answer was obtained combinatorially and amounts to $1/1,889,706,425\approx 5.3\cdot10^{-10}.$ I understand the combinatorial approach, but I do not understand where I go wrong with my solution. Is it my initial assumption?

Comment: The problem is not clear.  In each part, do I get to choose whether I want true-false or multiple choice or is that decided for me?  If I get to choose, what rule do I follow?  If it is decided for me, what rule is followed?  The problem statement says I get to choose but the computation appears to assume something else.

Comment: To be clear:  Commonsense would say that I choose the one I expect to do better on.  For the first part, choosing true false has a mean of $5$, while choosing multiple choice has a mean of $\frac 85$ so choosing the latter would seem to be irrational.